# Ansible: escape quotes and listing users password expiry information

Tags: ansible

How to escape in shell module quotation?
I've tried as follows:

```
- name: UList
  shell: "cut -f 1 -d: /etc/passwd | sudo xargs -n 1 -I {} bash -c \" echo {} ; chage -l {}\""
```

and

```
- name: UList
  shell: "cut -f 1 -d: /etc/passwd | sudo xargs -n 1 -I {} bash -c \' echo {} ; chage -l {}\'"
```

Where is a mistake?

Comment: Can you tell me what you trying to achieve with above command?

Comment: I want to list all users in the system with the username and password expiry information.

Comment: Solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This playbook worked for me, hope this will be helpful for you too. You can use single quotes`'` for a command if you have an issue escaping `"` quote

Either do it this way

`'cut -f 1 -d: /etc/passwd | sudo xargs -n 1 -I {} bash -c " echo {} ; chage -l {}"'`
Or

`"cut -f 1 -d: /etc/passwd | sudo xargs -n 1 -I {} bash -c ' echo {} ; chage -l {}'"`

Both are working i have tested it.

```
---
- name: Set my hosts variable
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: UList
    shell: 'cut -f 1 -d: /etc/passwd | sudo xargs -n 1 -I {} bash -c " echo {} ; chage -l {}"'
    register: result
  - name: debug
    debug:
     msg: "{{result}}"
```

**Or**

For the output you are expecting for that you can use

`awk -F':' '{ system("echo " $1 " && chage -l " $1)  }' /etc/passwd`

[**Command explanation**](https://serverfault.com/questions/295125/dump-output-list-linux-password-expiry-info-for-all-users/852651#852651)

```
---
- name: Set my hosts variable
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: UList
    shell: "awk -F':' '{ system(\"echo \" $1 \" && chage -l \" $1)  }' /etc/passwd"
    register: result
  - name: debug
    debug:
     msg: "{{result}}"
```

Comment: @kurgulus Welcome... :)